# Beam unable to detect delimiter when reading file using TextIO.read in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am stuck at deciding right delimiter for my file which has new line character after few lines, even after multiple attempts Iam not able to figure out right delimiter for my file. I have following file in Cloud storage bucket. The file looks as below

```
hello1
hello1
hello1

hello2
hello2
hello2
```

The java Beam code I have written is

```
        PCollection<String> rows= pipeline.apply("Read From GCS", TextIO.read().from(options.getBucketName()).withDelimiter(new byte[] {'\n', '\n'}));
        rows.apply("print", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx){
                String data = ctx.element();
                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println("******************");

            }
        }));
```

I have printed '***' just to see if file is split into pcollection correctly or not after each element. But looks like all text in file is stored as single element which defeats the purpose of parallelizing. The output of maven dataflow program execution is as follows

```
 483 ms and produced 1 files and 9 bundles
hello1
hello1
hello1

hello2
hello2
hello2

******************
```

I have written simple program in python to check if file has any problem. Interestingly it divided elements correctly as below screenshot

[image]

In short why is my delimiter not working in java Beam code. Iam working on windows machine and my file is in cloud storage and using maven to execute beam program and iam using java1.8 SDK. Also tried all possible delimiters {'\r', '\n'} and {"\n", "\n"} (this was throwing error and did not compile) but nothing worked. Any help is really appreciated. Already got to know that delimiter option is not available in python Beam.

Comment: What is the beam version? And the above output is for Dataflow Runner or is it same for DirectRunner as well?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Nirley. Yes tried in Dataflow Runner as well but same result. Its not splitting. Nothing is working even regex is not working inside beam function but in plain java everything works.

Comment: What beam version are you using? I would like to try and reproduce the issue.